# which version should I choose to show google maps view in my android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've tried V1 and V3, and both of them got me the same result: no map , no error , just grid.

I'm sure that I put the key.

Is the problem in the version. Should I use V3?

I don't find clear tutorials for V3 like V2 & V1. (Videos are the simplest way)

If V2 is still working, what do u think is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using V2. and Your api key is most likely the culprit for this issue.

I've seen it multiple times.  Verify your api key is included correctly and is the right api key to use with your app.

Comment: Thank u for your answer. Could u mention some mistakes in using API key? because I repeat it several times and it got exactly the same result.

Comment: common mistakes is not using the right api key or using the right debug.keystore and not including it correctly in the manifest. from what I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get started using Google Maps API v2 is to generate a debug key using the debug keystore.  On Windows the debug keystore is called `debug.keystore` and should be located in the following directory:

```
C:\Users\your_user_name\.android
```

Once you locate the debug keystore get the SHA1 by entering the following command in the command prompt:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Use this SHA1 to generate your API key and you should be able to finally see the map.

[More detailed information about creating a debug and release API key can be found here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#display_your_apps_certificate_information)